# Some SO users neither accept answers nor give any response

Tags: discussion

As you can see my profile for Stack Overflow, many of my answers have not been accepted, and in some cases, there has been no reply from the OP.

So what should we consider in such cases? Should consider that the question has been resolved or that our answer is wrong or something else?

When other SO users come across a question with no accepted answer, how will they know which answer is acceptable and which one is not?

Comment: [How unsung am I?](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/7521/how-unsung-am-i)

Comment: I guess Its not duplicate.Because that question is for Newbie specific only and I am asking that Those who have good reputation and allow for down vote, why are they not responding ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You move on. We cannot force anyone to respond or accept answers.

Remember that you help not only the OP but any future visitors as well. If your answer is truly helpful, you'll receive up votes from those people, over time.